# Parsing remote xml file with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

Could somebody explain me why the following script does not work? Thanks ;-)

```
$("#getRate").on("click", function(event) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      getRates(xhttp);
    }
  }

  xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/EUR/2016-06-02", true);
  xhttp.send();

  function getRates(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("testRate").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ExchangeRatesSeries")[0].getElementsByTagName("Rates")[0].getElementsByTagName("Rate")[0].getElementsByTagName("Mid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }

});
```

Comment: You have passed xhttp object directy.but you have to pass xhttp.responseText as the parameter for getRates method.

Answer (score 0):

The code xml.responseXml will null. Because, in the request it will return value in responseText. If you want responseXml has value,  you must define Content-Type is text/xml. 
Updated: to prevent cross domain you can convert responseText to json. You need the mid value and changed your code as below

```
function getRates(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseText;
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + xmlDoc + ')');
    document.getElementById("testRate").innerHTML = jsonObj.rates[0].mid;
}
```

Comment: The object seems not to be ready (xhttp.readyState, xhttp.status), but I am able to open the document in my browser... http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/EUR/2016-06-02

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this solution does not work crossdomain... I have to download the files first and the parse them locally. Then the script works fine.